# jQuery animate is not working in Android 4.0

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap, jquery and phonegap in my application.

I have a div with overflow:scroll and two buttons to navigate through it:

```
    <a href="#" id="left-button" style="float: left;"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a href="#" id="right-button" style="float: right;"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    <div id="content" style="overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap;">
        <img src="img/bandera.jpg" class="img-rounded">
        <img src="img/arbol.jpg" class="img-rounded">
    </div>
```

I have the next jquery script to use the buttons:

```
   $('#right-button').click(function(){
       $('#content').animate({
           scrollLeft: '+=200px'
       }, 600 );
     });
   $('#left-button').click(function(){
       $('#content').animate({
           scrollLeft: '-=200px'
       }, 600 );
     });
```

But I have a problem. The buttons works fine in Firefox, Chrome and even in IE in my desktop, and works fine in Android 2.2

But for some reason, in Android 4.0 the buttons do nothing.

Comment: If I change 'overflow: scroll' to 'overflow: hidden' the buttons are working in Android 4.0 and 2.2, but then I cant scroll through the div with my finger (usual scroll) in Android 4.0...

Comment: I have the same issue - indeed, when setting scrolling to 'hidden', it works as expected ...but the div is not scrolable then ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jquery-1.9.1.js, 
I have the same issue with the jquery-1.8.2.js on Android 2.3.6 device.
I finally resolved it by upgrading to jquery-1.9.1.js.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12497

Comment: Well... Although I already resolve this in the past (With a really horrible workaround that I wont reproduce here), now with the new jQuery version works fine, so... Your answer is good :)

Answer (score 0):

Will you try this one.

```
 $('#left-button').live("click", function(){
       $('#content').animate({
           scrollLeft: '-=200px'
       }, 600 );
     });
```

Comment: Nop, same as the original: Works in desktop and in android 2.2 ; but no in 4.0. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So, the simplest workaround I tried is to set the CSS overflow property to hidden right before animate and restore it back to 'scroll'/'auto' when complete handler is called.

The problem is that when I set 'overflow' back to 'scroll', the scrollable div just goes up to top...Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

scrollLeft doesn't work in Android, it is a known bug in Android browsers (4.0.3+).

[Check out this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641898/jquery-scrollleft-not-working-on-android)

Instead you could use the "left" property of the inner element.