# Image resizing fail jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

When using jQuery .animate() function on images, all works fine on desktops, but using my android 4.2 device and browser, it fails.

I use the function to animate an image resize. As soon as the animation starts, I get a duplicate image in my mobile browser with the original size. This duplicate image also stays there when the animation is completed.

Anyone recognizes this? Is this a jQuery fail or can it by my own failure?

```
    $( "#imageID" ).animate( { height: "67px" }, 1500 );
```

Comment: may be this is similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835080/jquery-animate-is-not-working-in-android-4-0

Comment: use latest jquery version ..

Comment: Done some tests. It has nothing to do with overflows, so not the same problem as mentioned by @Dinesh. I use the latest jQuery version (1.9.1 for jQuery and 1.9.2 for jQuery UI)

I execute the function after all images have loaded, so unloaded images are also not a problem